# Can I prevent my system from creating .Trash-1000 folders on network shares?

Tags: samba, thunar

Let's assume that I'm not going to remember to hit shift-delete every time I remove (temporary) files on a network share, or to delete using `rm` when I'm working on the share (as discussed previously [for USB drives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/374683/47326)).

My temporary files when working on a particular samba share can be rather large and clutter the drive up when deleted (typically using Thunar), which displeases the owner of the share.  I'd like to not create the `.Trash-1000` directory in the first place, while maintaining the normal behaviour on local drives.  Is there some way (client-side) to disable this?  Or an alternative method I haven't thought of to prevent the creation, or remove the folder once created?